# Add Multiple ArrayLists to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I am trying to list text and images in a list format in the recyclerview and display in each row this my code and I know its wrong cause its only showing one row how must I edit the code. Still learning java

```
ArrayList<DataList> dataList = new ArrayList<DataList>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i ++ ) {

        dataList.add(new DataList(

                "France",
                "Russia",
                R.drawable.lt1,
                "America",
                "Europe",
                R.drawable.lt2
        ));
    }

    ArrayList<DataList2> dataList2 = new ArrayList<DataList2>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i ++ ) {

        dataList2.add(new DataList2(

                "South Africa",
                "Brazil",
                R.drawable.lt1,
                "New Zeland",
                "Pakistan",
                R.drawable.lt2
        ));
    }
```

Comment: if you want to add items only one time then why are you using loop?

Comment: Please paste code of adapter

Answer (score 0):

***You are iterating the loop only `1` time .***

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i ++ ) {
                    /\
                    ||
                 Iterate it more times
}
```

Like

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++ ) {// n times or as much as you want 

}
```

Comment: thats not the problem it must only show DataList one time then DataList2 in the second row under it but its only showing DataList

Answer (score 0):

You should be adding them to one main ArrayList of items which the RecyclerView will then show.